# display all field codes (instead of results)

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-field

I need to display the fields code and use:

```
Document.Content.Fields.ToggleShowCodes
```

I have fields, some are in text boxes and need showing all of them.

But the above toggles - and I need more control. If the codes are showing, performs display fields results.

So I need if fields code are showing, do nothing, else show all fields code, even if they're are in the text boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `View.ShowFieldCodes` property which takes/accepts a Boolean:

```
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
```

It doesn't matter whether any or no field codes are currently displayed: ALL will be displayed.